# Multiple amcharts5 in one page

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

Multiple charts on one page using **amchart5**  with separate root elements

I am trying to create multiple stacked bar chart using amcharts version 5.
One chart is getting rendered properly but when I am trying to add second chart it is not rendering any charts at all.

I am using 2 root elements for 2 charts

```
this.chart1 = am5.Root.new("chartid1") 
this.chart2 = am5.Root.new("chartid2")
```

could you please let me know how to render these 2 charts on a single page

Comment: There's no restriction in adding multiple charts to the same page, as you can see from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2wybjrt/). However, the boilerplate code specific to amcharts makes it very easy to get mistakes - for instance, for the simplest chart, there are 5 references to the `root` variable. And since a second chart is usually started with a copy of the first's code, it's very likely that you have a wrong reference in the second chart to the first one's `root`, `chart`, `xAxis`, `yAxis`, or `series` variables. If you still don't find the problem, please post your code here.